# Как закодировать 16-ричное число в swift по стандарту base64?

Tags: ios, swift

Нужно в консоли вводить с клавиатуры последовательность. Пример ввода: 43 61 74.Пример вывода: Q2FO

Comment: Нужно так нужно, вводите. И каким образом из этого ввода получается такой вывод?

Comment: На самом деле должно получится `Q2F0`. На входе слово `Cat` зачем-то записанное хексом

Comment: а у вас есть код?

Answer (score 0):

Например так можно - читаете ввод с помощью `readLine()` и передаете в функцию

```
func convertToBase64(_ string: String) -> String? {
    // разбиваем строку
    let parts = string.split (separator:" ")
    let decText = parts.map { item -> String in
        // конвертируем в unichar
        guard let dec = unichar(item, radix:16) else {
            return ""
        }
        // конвертируем в символы
        return String(format: "%C", dec)
    }.joined()

    return decText.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()
}
```