# Неправильно работает алгоритм кодирования base64

Tags: ios, swift

Не правильно работает алгоритм кодирования 16-ричных чисел. Должно получиться так:
Пример ввода: 0F DD A4 12
Пример вывода: D92kEg==

```
func convertToBase64(_ string: String) -> String? {
        // разбиваем строку
        let parts = string.split (separator:" ")
        let decText = parts.map { item -> String in
            // конвертируем в unichar
            guard let dec = unichar(item, radix:16) else {
                return ""
            }
            // конвертируем в символы
            return String(format: "%C", dec)
        }.joined()

        return decText.data(using: .utf8)?.base64EncodedString()
    }
```

Comment: Я думаю, что правильно будет обратиться к [автору этого кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1062021/282277) за разъяснением, а не выдавать этот код за свой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код взят из [моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1061978/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-16-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2-swift-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-base64/1062021#1062021). Преобразование в строку дает `Ý¤` (первый и последний символ управляющие и не отображаются), что в свою очередь дает base64 `D8OdwqQS` в **кодировке UTF-8**. Вывод `D92kEg==` получается при использовании кодировки `ISO-8859-1`, она же `Latin-1` (проверить можно например [здесь](https://www.base64encode.org/))

Соответственно для получения нужного вам результата нужно поменять кодировку

```
return decText.data(using: .isoLatin1)?.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: Большое  спасибо, а как вводить с клавиатуры длину последовательности, типа первая строка 4(длина кодируемой последовательности), а вторая сама последовательность: 0F DD A4 12?

Comment: @user365039 это уже другой вопрос, который вы можете оформить отдельно, если мой ответ вас устроил, поставьте галку рядом с ним